# R named list - names() returns NULL

Tags: r, list

Hi I am new to R and have a simple question:

I was trying out named lists, but for some reason the name I am giving is ignored:

```
foo <- list(
  bar <- 5
)
names(foo)
# NULL
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Could you copy the relevant part of your console output into the body of your question as text please?  Not everyone can easily read text in images.

Comment: You have to use `=` there because technically you want to specify an argument to the `list` function: `foo <- list(bar = 5)`

Comment: Thank you @Roland :) the two assignment operators are quite misleading, the '<-' seems to address some higher variable space

Comment: No, `<-` assigns `5` to `bar` and returns `5` invisibly. As a result, `list` only gets this invisible return value as input. Your code actually creates a variable `bar` in the global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before posting ,capture some basic in R.

Your Answer:

```
 foo <- list(
      bar = 5 ,car=10
    )
    names(foo)
    foo
```

And for more basic information search here : http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list